# How can I share a url from a browser to my app in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

#### TL/DR

How can I make an iOS app appear on share sheet to receive shared urls from any other app?

This is a super newbie post as I have never really touched swift to develop anything, but I couldnt find the answer to my question on google so i wanted to start here. Almost everything I found by googling around is `UIActivityViewController` which appears more to be about how to share content from my app to another app; while what I am trying to do is share urls from another app to my app.

I am try to build a simple app for ios (doesnt have to be old version compatible because it will be only used by me) that can be a receiver for shared urls from apps like safari, brave or youtube. All the app does is when user clicks on the share button, and then chooses the app, the app gets the relevant data that is being passed, and then posts it to a backend server.

I can accomplish this on my android app/devices with an intent filter action `android.intent.action.SEND` in the manifest, and then listening for it with `Intent intent = getIntent()` in my method.

Would someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction at what I should look into (google about). If you can also point me to some sample code examples on how to write an app that can be the receiver for shared data (like urls), that would be fantastic. I am not sure what to search for so that my app can show up on share sheet, and how to then react with the data.

Again, apologies for the super noob question, but I couldnt translate my idea to something relevant on google.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is "Deep links". You can use firebase for that.

Comment: Not deep links. In android, one can set intent receivers while setting the appropriate activity filters in the manifest. So for example, if one is using the slack app in iOS, and they select share from safari, slack is an option to share into. that is what I am trying to achieve. Make an app that I can share links to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by an Action Extension. Search for it.

Here is one:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-how-to-build-a-simple-action-extension--cms-22794

Comment: I still haven't found a way to do this that doesn't rely on unsupported hacks (use of private/prohibited API). Would love to see a simple example of this actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

I think both Share extension and Action extension can do the job. It depends on your needs.

Check [this table](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW3) to make sure which one is more appropriate for your purpose.

You can refer to [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html) by Apple.